# $\{(x,t) \in X \times R : f(x) < t < g(x)\}$ is homeomorphic to $X \times R$

Tags: general-topology

Let X be topological space and $f,g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. For every $x \in X$, $f(x)<g(x)$. Prove that $\{(x,t) \in X \times \mathbb{R} : f(x) < t < g(x)\}$ is homeomorphic to $X \times \mathbb{R}$.

My idea is to show that $\{(x,t) \in X \times \mathbb{R} : f(x) < t < g(x)\} = X \times (m, M)$

where $m=\inf f(x)$ and $M=\sup g(x)$. But I don't know how to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** You may instead to show that your space is homeomorphic to $X\times (0,1)$. Now consider the map $(x,t)\mapsto (x, tf(x)+(1-t)g(x))$ from $X\times (0,1)$ to your space.

Comment: I know how to show that (a, b) homeomorphic to R. Other part i dont know.

Comment: @Ggi Could I ask which part is not comprehensible to you? Is it showing $X\times \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $X\times(0,1)$, or showing the given map is a homeomorphism?

Comment: For the latter, we need to find an inverse map which is continuous. For $x\in X$ and $t$ such that $f(x)<t<g(x)$, consider the map $(x,t)\mapsto \left(x, \frac{t-f(x)}{g(x)-f(x)}\right)$

Comment: I see, i misunderstood. I will try what you have written. Thank you